# Angular 8 back button and parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I have an app that I need to get some parameters to the navigated route when browser back button is clicked.
I have Home view that I have Datefrom and DateTo. When I navigate to Catalog from Home View I pass Datefrom and DateTo parameters. I successfully receive them on the new route. However when I click back button how can I receive the datefrom and dateto in the Home view (previous route)?
Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-t84tru) with my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an Angular event listener in your Catalog Component to detect popstate event
on the window object then store data once the event triggered and fetch it in home component using a shared service. Here is a working example:

**DataService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private dates = new BehaviorSubject({});

  constructor() {}

  fetchDates(): Observable<any> {
    return this.dates.asObservable();
  }

  sendDates(dateFrom: Date, dateTo: Date) {
    this.dates.next({dateFrom: dateFrom, dateTo: dateTo});
  }

}
```

**Catalog Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: "catalog",
  template: `
    <h1>Catalog</h1>
  `
})
export class CatalogViewComponent implements OnInit {
  dateFrom: Date;
  dateTo: Date;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private dataService: DataService) {

  }

  @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  onPopState(event) {
    console.log('Back button pressed');
    this.dataService.sendDates(this.dateFrom, this.dateTo);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.route.snapshot.params["dateFrom"])
      this.dateFrom = new Date(+this.route.snapshot.params["dateFrom"]);

    if (this.route.snapshot.params["dateTo"])
      this.dateTo = new Date(+this.route.snapshot.params["dateTo"]);

  }

}
```

**Home Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: "home",
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <h3>Total users: # {{ users?.length }}</h3>
      <button (click)="navigate()">Click</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class HomeViewComponent implements OnInit {
  users;
  dateFrom: Date;
  dateTo: Date;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.fetchDates().subscribe(dates => {
      this.dateFrom = dates.dateFrom;
      this.dateTo = dates.dateTo;
    });
    console.log(this.dateFrom);
    console.log(this.dateTo);
  }
  constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router, private dataService: DataService) {
    this.http
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(res => (this.users = res));
  }
  navigate() {
    //initialize values to send
    this.dateFrom = new Date();
    this.dateTo = new Date();

    this.router.navigate([
      "/catalog",
      {
        dateFrom: this.dateFrom.valueOf(),
        dateTo: this.dateTo.valueOf()
      }
    ]);
  }
}
```

**AppModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
import {DataService} from './data.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent],
  imports: [ 
    AppRoutingModule, 
    BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule 
  ],
  providers: [DataService],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thabka for your reply. I wanted to avoid having a service event listeners and states and I was looking for a way to do this based on angular router. From what I can see angular does not support this out of the box

Answer (score 0):

**One Way:**

Use

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/catelog', { state: { dateFromVariable: dateFrominputValue,dateToVariable:dateToInputvalue } });
```

in the navigate() in ts component of home to preserve the state of dateFrom and dateTo variables when you are switching routes by using "state" object.

**Second Way:**

Use

```
[state]="{ dateFromVariable: dateFrominputValue,dateToVariable:dateToInputvalue }
```

in HTML template .

You can read the values using **window.history.state** property.

Comment: but If I navigate on other pages that do not have any relationship with the params and then visit Home again, it should not read parameters from the state. Parameters should only be ready if I come from the Catalog page

Comment: try with @viewChild in angular which carries value from one component to another component.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the back button refreshes the page. So to keep your dates saved you need to do one of 2 options:

1) sessionStorage to store and retrieve data (save it when retrieved and then if it does not exist get it from session storage).

```
let fromAndTodates = [];
if (dates) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('dates', JSON.stringify(dates));
  fromAndTodates = dates;
} else {
  fromAndTodates = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('dates'));
}
```

2) Save it as a query parameter across all pages (I saw that you already do that in one page) so that if the user tried to go back he still can fetch the data from the url.

```
export class HomeViewComponent {
  dates;

  constructor(
    private actR: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dates = this.actR.queryParams;
  }

  navigate(url) {
     this.router.navigate([
      url,
      {
        dateFrom: this.dates.dateFrom, //retrieved with ActivatedRoute
        dateTo: this.dates.dateTo
      }
    ]); // it will take urls with it
  }
}
```

In HTML

```
<a (click)="navigate('/about')">About</a>
```

Comment: how can I save it as query parameter when I hit back button?

Comment: Not when you hit the back button. You save the dates as query params wherever you need them so that when you click back, you still find them. I know you may think that would be messy in the url and that's why I added it as a second option.

Comment: how can I save it as query params?

Comment: Instead of a normal [routerLink] you will create a (click) event that triggers navigate(url) with the url to the page you want to visit as a parameter as in the example above (just updated it).

Comment: But I dont hit a link or click somewhere in html to go back. I just hit back button of browser

Comment: Here is the process: 1) You access your Home page with no date filter. 2) you select date filter 3) when the date fields changed, navigate(url) function get triggered to navigate to the same page but with query params added. 4) user go to inner page also using navigate() 5) even when user click back button, the previous query params remains.

Comment: but this is what I am doing in the stackblitz that I created but I dont get the parameters. Note that I am not navigating to an inner page but rather to a totally different route